# Regular expression to match href, but no media files

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this regex to math all contents of `href's` on a page:

> (?:href)=[\"|']?(.*?)[\"|'|>]+

It works fine. But i want to match only links that are not media like (png|jpg|avi|wav|gif) etc.

I tried something like adding

> ((?!png).)

to my regex, but this did not work. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)
but could not get any working solution.

Comment: Regex is almost never a good choice for parsing XML based documents.  But once you get the href value, instantiate a URI to do the path dissection.

Comment: i think it is more performant than using htmlagilitypack or something else for xml parsing. or is it more performant?

Comment: performance isn't necessarilly the issue, it is the fact that hrefs can come in many different forms that your code might not cover but a true XML or HTML parser would.

Comment: I agree with @StefanH - the more I look at what you are try to do, the more problems I see with it. You're gut feeling that regex can do the job [is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/211627), but you are underestimating just how complicated the task will be. You should strongly consider the HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: If you dont like htmlagilitypack there's always MSHTML.  Or if you are parsing XHTML then you can use the System.Xml namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
List<string> href = new List<string>();

private void addHREF()
{
    //put your input to check
    string input = "";

    doc.LoadHtml(input);
    //Which files ignore?
    string[] stringArray = { ".png", ".jpg" };
    foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
    {
        string value = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
        if (stringArray.Any(value.Contains) == false)
            href.Add(value);
    }
}
```

I tested with my input works great... if you have any problem let me know..

Comment: thanks, i finally switched from regex to htmlagilitypack - works fine. so this one is accepted answers. but others regex's are nice too! thanks all

Answer (score 3):

I know this question was already answered.

I'd like to offer a different approach using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) instead of `HtmlAgilityPack`

I think the syntax is more compact and is very similar to other structures since it's based on `LINQ`

```
//input is your input HTML string
var links = CQ.Create(input).Find("a").Select(x=>x.Cq().Attr("href"));
```

For example

```
var links = CQ.Create("<div><a href='blah'></a><a href='blah2'></a></div>").Find("a").Select(x=>x.Cq().Attr("href"));
Console.Write(string.Join(",",dom)); //prints blah,blah2
```

Hope this helps anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though I recommend against this approach, you may find this regex helpful:

```regex
(?<=href\s*=\s*['"]?)(?>(https?://)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([/\w\.-]*)*/?)(?<!png|gif|etc)
```

*(Based on URL regex from [8 Regular Expressions You Should Know](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/))*

Note that this expression will not allow spaces in the URL. This is because HREF's without quotes will match the following attribute (for example, `"domain.com/resource.txt title"`)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{

    string l_input =
        "<a href=\n" +
        "        \"HTTPS://example.com/page.html\" title=\"match\" />\n" +
        "<a href='http://site.com/pic.png' title='do not match'> <a href=domain.com/resource.txt title=match>\n" +
        " <script src=scripts.com/script.js>";

    foreach ( Match l_match in Regex.Matches( l_input, @"(?<=href\s*=\s*['""]?)(?>(https?://)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([/\w\.-]*)*/?)(?<!png|gif|etc)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) )
        Console.WriteLine( "'" + l_match.Value + "'" );

    /* 
     * Returns:
     * 
     * HTTPS://example.com/page.html
     * domain.com/resource.txt
     *          
     */

    Console.ReadKey( true );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My effort

```
@"(?<=\shref\s*=\s*[""']?)(?![""']|\S+\.(?:png|jpg|avi|wav|gif)[""']?[\s>])\S+?(?=[""']?[\s>])";
```

It uses a positive look-behind to locate the content, and a negative lookahead to make sure it doesn't contain a dot followed by either of *png jpg avi wav gif* followed by an optional quote mark and a space or `>`. It then matches up until an optional quote mark followed by a space or `>`. The content does not have to be quoted but it must not contain whitespace.

Comment: This will not match `href   =   "http..."` (spaces). Otherwise, not bad.

Comment: @Cyborgx37. Updated to allow space around the `=`, and to allow non-quoted content.